# MongoDB-Projecting a field behaves weird

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm not able to project `title` unless I add `title: 1` two times as given in the below query. Can anyone explain why and how to get around with it?

```
db.movies.aggregate([

{$match: {
   languages: {$elemMatch : {$eq: "English"}},
   "imdb.rating":{$gte: 1},
   "imdb.votes":{$gte: 1},
   year: {$gte: 1990}
}},
{$project:
   {scaled_votes: {$add: [1, {$multiply: [9, {$divide: [{$subtract:
     ["$imdb.votes",5]},{$subtract: [1521105,5]}]}]}]},
      "imdb.rating": 1,
       title: 1
    }

  },
  {$project: 
    {           
        normalized_rating: {$avg:["$scaled_votes","$imdb.rating"]},title: 1
    }
   },
   {$sort: {normalized_rating: 1}},
   {$limit: 1}


  ])
```

Sample data:

```
/* 1 */
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("573a1398f29313caabcebce8"),
"title" : "12:01 PM",
"year" : 1990,
"runtime" : 25,
"cast" : [ 
    "Jane Alden", 
    "Don Amendolia", 
    "John Bachelder", 
    "Rick Ford"
],
"plot" : "A man is stuck living his life in the same 59 minute time frame. He tries various methods of finding out why, eventually consulting a physicist.",
"fullplot" : "A man is stuck living his life in the same 59 minute time frame. He tries various methods of finding out why, eventually consulting a physicist.",
"lastupdated" : "2015-06-04 00:41:47.527000000",
"type" : "movie",
"languages" : [ 
    "English"
],
"directors" : [ 
    "Jonathan Heap"
],
"writers" : [ 
    "Stephen Tolkin", 
    "Jonathan Heap", 
    "Richard Lupoff (short story)"
],
"imdb" : {
    "rating" : 7.8,
    "votes" : 856,
    "id" : 98962
},
"countries" : [ 
    "USA"
],
"genres" : [ 
    "Sci-Fi", 
    "Short"
],
"tomatoes" : {
    "viewer" : {
        "rating" : 0.0,
        "numReviews" : 0
    },
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2015-09-14T18:07:54.000Z")
},
"num_mflix_comments" : 2,
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Daenerys Targaryen",
        "email" : "emilia_clarke@gameofthron.es",
        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1398f29313caabcebce8"),
        "text" : "Quasi praesentium libero sapiente quae. Maiores cupiditate laboriosam porro quas cupiditate fugiat. Ipsum sunt in natus atque. Doloribus numquam recusandae harum repudiandae eos assumenda.",
        "date" : ISODate("2004-02-23T07:08:24.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Robert Smith",
        "email" : "robert_smith@fakegmail.com",
        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1398f29313caabcebce8"),
        "text" : "Nesciunt magnam doloremque deserunt. Itaque culpa a ad optio sint impedit mollitia provident. Impedit aut assumenda ab cupiditate repudiandae dolore.",
        "date" : ISODate("1970-09-03T23:22:31.000Z")
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I managed to get around and removed `limit:1` for one occurrence. 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahul-raj/MongoDB/master/movies.js

However, I'm still wondering how can I fix the above query without having to think about `$addFields`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$project operator requires you  to list the new and existing fields.

Replace your both project stages with below project stage.

```
{
  $project: {
    normalized_rating: {
      $avg: [
        {
          $add: [
            1,
            {
              $multiply: [
                9,
                {
                  $divide: [
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        "$imdb.votes",
                        5
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        1521105,
                        5
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "$imdb.rating"
      ]
    },
    title: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortest solution, I was just wondering why `title` is not getting projected if I include `title:1` only at once (first or last in the pipeline of above query)

Comment: Np. That is how aggregation works. Aggregation works by passing data from one stage to another. match and sort stages applies filtering and sorting on the data while project and group stages are used to transform the data by listing the fields that you will require for next stage. In next stage you use the fields from previous stage and define the fields you want to keep for next stage and so on. addFields on the other hand makes it easy by keeping existing fields when you define new fields.

Comment: Did my answer/ comment help you ? Let me know.